# Autoscaling is working but continuously 502 coming on Google Flexible Environment (NodeJs)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-flexible

[image: Logs]

```html
# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: 'frontend'
env_variables:
  DEPLOY_ENV: 'PRODUCTION'
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: IGNORED
  secure: always
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 4
# [END app_yaml]
```

Autoscaling is working but continuously 502 coming on Google Flexible Environment (NodeJs). See logs, response time is only 0, 1 and sometimes it's more than that. Any help would be very appreciated.

[image: Log]

[image: Log]

Comment: I need more information, please expand the request log and also provide the resources being hit so there's more for me work with.

Comment: I have added log image, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Are all your requests getting 502s or only some of them? Did you have it working before? What changes did you make?

If all your requests are getting 502s and it's never worked before, then it's likely you don't have it setup properly. Please [make sure your app is listening to port 8080](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#code) and it should work.

If it worked before and it's continue to work now without any code change, then any transient issue should be investigated on our end. Please file a issue on our [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/#about_issue_tracker), thanks.

Comment: Some requests are getting 502 (Randomly). It's not like one or two end point is getting 502. Its coming on random requests and 502 comes continuously around 10 per second. App setup is fine (https://hero.wooplr.com/) and we have been using gae from last 4 years.

Comment: If no code changes were made and it does work a majority of the time, then it's like an issue that needs to be investigated on our end. I updated my answer.